# Deployment fails on Google App Engine "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'"

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, gcloud

I am a new GCP user. I'm working with **Django** project. I want deploy my project on **Google App Engine** using command line `gcloud app deploy`. But I have a problem.

I have sent this problem on Google discussion but I did not get an answer so far.

I saw the logs but, I do not understand.

These are my **logs**:
[image: log]

requirements file

```html
Django==2.1.7
djangorestframework==3.9.1
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-filter==2.1.0
factory-boy==2.10.0
coreapi==2.3.3
django-anymail==6.0
dj_database_url==0.5.0
python-decouple==3.0
setuptools==38.5.1
pip==19.0.3
pytz==2018.3
certifi==2018.1.18
wheel==0.30.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
google-cloud-datastore==1.9.0
google-cloud-storage==1.19.1
```

Comment: Please add the project's `requirements.txt` to your question. It's curious that pip `19.0.3` is being uninstalled (!) and `9.0.3` is being installed during the deployment. It could be unrelated to your issue but, you should not  include `pip` in your `requirements.txt`

Comment: Please don't post images of text, instead copy-paste the text in your post and format it accordingly. Thx.

Comment: @DazWilkin thank you very much. my version pip was actually on 9.0.3. I did not report. I put it back to 19.0.2 and it worked

Comment: @DanCornilescu well understood

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:

Please add the project's `requirements.txt` to your question.

It's curious that pip 19.0.3 is being uninstalled (!) and 9.0.3 is being installed during the deployment.

It could be unrelated to your issue but, you should not include pip in your `requirements.txt`